# Solving "Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering" error

Tags: geojson, error, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to analyze GeoJSON data using Pandas library but getting this error:

> Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.

How am able to eliminate the error since the output i need to incorparate in Django view and i dont want to use GeoPandas?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do exactly?

I got the error when trying to create a Pandas data frame with

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Where `data` was a dict containing the data for the data frame.

The problem was that one of the values within the dict was a dict itself.
I removed the corresponding entry and the problem went away.

Comment: what i need is to use pandas to read geojson data